# Specific issue with a fetch request on input

Tags: input, fetch, disabled-input

I have an input field and when on input a function is called. It stops the timeout if there is one, if not then we know the user stopped typing. If the timeout finishes it makes a fetch request to determine if the user's input is valid. Lastly, if the fetch request returns valid, the user's input goes into a list. It will never be valid if a special character exists.

My problem is that when a user enters a valid input, after the 1-second timeout finishes, if the user just happens to within that microsecond window between the fetch and the sending to the list a user enters a special character... the user's valid input plus the special character will go into the list.
My solution is to disable the input field while awaiting the pending promise to resolve (which takes maybe a quarter of a second).

My boss however wants me to see if there is a better solution out there. Since my situation feels rather unique I thought I'd just ask other developers if they perhaps did have a better solution.
Thank you for your help everyone.

The code is something like:

```
    function (){
    if (timeoutexists){
        clearTimeout
    }
    timeout = setTimeout ({
        submitting = true
        fetch user input
        submitting = false
if fetch resolve input is valid and put users input in list else it's invalid and do not put user input in list.
    })
    }
```

Comment: you will need to maintain another state variable that tells you whether or not you are fetching data.
so if fetching: ignore the input and do not enter into the array.

Comment: I'm already doing this. I said so in my OP. "My solution is to disable the input field while awaiting the pending promise to resolve (which takes maybe a quarter of a second)."